# Lifetime of a temporary object in subexpression

Tags: c++

Function `foo()` receives a `const char *` as its parameter, just like `strlen()`

`void foo(const char *p);`

Now I have an `std::string s = "some characters"`. What if I call

`foo(s.substr(1, 2).c_str());`

What is the lifespan of the `substr` object? Will it be kept until function returns? I'm concerned that it would be use-after-free if `substr` is destroyed before `foo()` enters.

Comment: It is guaranteed to exist until the statement is complete - which is after the function returns.

Comment: It's complex subject about [evaluation order and sequencing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order), but in short sub-expressions and their temporaries are valid until the full expression is over.

Answer (score 0):

If you check [std::string::substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/), the function returns a newly constructed string object with its value initialized to a copy of a substring of this object. So it will be valid until `foo()` returns and it will not be destroyed before entering `foo()`.